# Samba via Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, server, samba, uninstall

I accidentally deleted my samba configuration setup. And I don't know how remove samba and reinstall the package. It errors. Please can someone help me with this? It our home file server.

Comment: We can't know how your configuration was set up. If you want help on the reinstall, [edit] your post and add the exact commands you input and the exact output you received. Do not post this information in comments.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove and install samba again (and than configure smbd server)
Try the following:

```
sudo apt-get purge samba samba-common
sudo rm -rf /etc/samba/ /etc/default/samba
sudo apt-get install samba
```

Comment: Thank you for that, but I redid everything back to zero.